# Bison: Production ignoring required syntax

Tags: grammar, bison, context-free-grammar

I have the following rule in my .y file:

```
statement:
  expression |
  REDUCE operator reductions ENDREDUCE |
  IF expression THEN statement_ ELSE statement_ ENDIF |
  CASE expression IS cases OTHERS ARROW statement_ ENDCASE 
  ;

cases:
  case cases | 
  ;

case:
  WHEN INT_LITERAL ARROW statement_ 
  ;
```

The `cases` statements is a list of case statements. After the cases, the `OTHERS ARROW statement_` portion is required as a default (like switch/case in programming) before the `ENDCASE` token. However, when testing it, it does not think it is a syntax error for not having it:

```
./compile < tests/syntax5.txt

   1  // Multiple errors
   2  
   3  function main a integer returns real;
syntax error, unexpected INTEGER, expecting ':'

   4      b: integer is * 2;
syntax error, unexpected MULOP

   5      c: real is 6.0;
   6  begin
   7      if a > c then
   8          b + / 4.;
syntax error, unexpected MULOP

   9      else
  10          case b is
  11              when => 2;
syntax error, unexpected ARROW, expecting INT_LITERAL

  12              when 2 => c;
  13          endcase;
  14      endif;
  15  end;
      
Lexical Errors: 0
Syntax Errors: 4
Semantic Errors: 0
Duplicate Identifier Errors: 0
Undeclared Errors: 0
Total Errors: 4
```

Did i set something up wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your error productions (a [mre] would be the most useful, as always), but I suspect that's an artifact of error recovery. Try an input where the missing clause is the only error.

Comment: Hi, you're right; it was error recovery related.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was error recovery. I added `error ';'` to the `case` rule:

```
case:
  WHEN INT_LITERAL ARROW statement_ |
  error ';'
  ;
```

And now see the error:

```
1  // Multiple errors
   2  
   3  function main a integer returns real;
syntax error, unexpected INTEGER, expecting ':'

   4      b: integer is * 2;
syntax error, unexpected MULOP

   5      c: real is 6.0;
   6  begin
   7      if a > c then
   8          b + / 4.;
syntax error, unexpected MULOP

   9      else
  10          case b is
  11              when => 2;
syntax error, unexpected ARROW, expecting INT_LITERAL

  12              when 2 => c;
  13          endcase;
syntax error, unexpected ENDCASE, expecting WHEN or OTHERS

  14      endif;
  15  end;
      
Lexical Errors: 0
Syntax Errors: 5
Semantic Errors: 0
Duplicate Identifier Errors: 0
Undeclared Errors: 0
Total Errors: 5
```